# Remove NoData from Data Frame to plot

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove No Data from the array.

```
   Site  Data        Mean_NDVI 
0  HARV  2017-06-21  0.881326 
1  HARV  2017-12-14  0.499184 
2  HARV  2017-09-09  0.859584 
3  HARV  2017-09-25  0.840061 
4  HARV  2017-01-28  --
5  HARV  2017-07-07  --
6  HARV  2017-03-01  --
7  HARV  2017-10-27  0.68816 
8  HARV  2017-05-20  0.811055 
9  HARV  2017-11-12  0.61324 
10 HARV  2017-07-23  0.820074
...
...
```

Used:

```
#ndvi_harv_clean.replace("--", np.nan)  
#ndvi_sjer_clean.replace("--", np.nan)
ndvi_harv_clean

ndvi_harv_clean['Mean_NDVI'].replace(np.nan, 'Unknown', inplace=True)
ndvi_harv_clean
```

But this does not work. What can be a problem?

Comment: This is a question for stackoverflow.com (no GIS component). What is your expected output? Dont you want to [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that some `Mean_NDVI` values are not `NaN`, but `--`. Therefore, you can remove rows whose value is `--`.

```
ndvi_harv_clean = ndvi_harv_clean[ ndvi_harv_clean ["Mean_NDVI"] != '--']

# you can reset index using
# ndvi_harv_clean = ndvi_harv_clean.reset_index()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work.  Yes I need to remove NaN data after,  but renaming "--" does not work. Really want to understand why?